# Python and regex, can't understand why some words are left out of the match

Tags: python, regex

```
s = ("If I’m not in a hurry, then I should stay. " +
"On the other hand, if I leave, then I can sleep.")
re.findall(r'[Ii]f (.*), then', s)
```

The output is:

```
I’m not in a hurry, then I should stay. On the other hand, if I leave
```

The question is: Why aren't the words "If" and "then" not included in the output?

Something like this:

```
If I’m not in a hurry, then I should stay. On the other hand, if I leave, then
```

Comment: You're grabbing just the bit in parenthesis. The "if" and "then" aren't part of that. Maybe try `r'([Ii]f .*, then)'`

Comment: Match between (..) is a general rule for regex in any language?

Comment: because `findall` captures the value of the group(pattern inside parentheses).

Comment: Regex has a specification and all languages that implement it mostly follow the spec.

Comment: Ok, now I understand! Thanks for the explanations!